# Позиционирование input в форме

Tags: html, css

Товарищи, всех приветствую! Изучаю вёрстку, столкнулся с такой проблемой: на скрине простая форма ввода данных для регистрации, как сделать отступы у input так, чтобы они все начинались условно с красной линии?
Приветствуются ответы в виде ссылок на полезные статьи по этой теме, всем откликнувшимся спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кусок кода для понимания, таким образом выстроены все связки p+input

```
<div>
    <p>Введите пароль: <input type="text" placeholder="Пароль" id="password" name="password"> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: .25em;
}

label {
  display: contents;
}

span::after {
  content: ":";
}

h1, h2 {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h1>Регистрация</h1>
  <label><span>Товарищи</span><input></label>
  <label><span>всех</span><input></label>
  <label><span>приветствую</span><input></label>
  <h2>Дополнительные поля</h2>
  <label><span>Изучаю</span><input></label>
  <label><span>вёрстку</span><input></label>
  <label><span>столкнулся</span><input></label>
  <label><span>с</span><input></label>
  <label><span>такой</span><input></label>
  <label><span>проблемой</span><input></label>
</form>
```